# Why does Handbrake keep cropping my videos?

Tags: video-conversion, handbrake

I have some 640x360 videos I want to re-encode with Handbrake to make their file size smaller. When I choose automatic cropping it shows 2 pixel cropping at the top and left, so I chose custom cropping, with everything set to zero.

[image]

Despite setting width to 640 and height to 360 Handbrake produces a 638x358 video, i.e. it still applies the cropping. Checking "Keep aspect ratio" doesn't help.

How can I let Handbrake keep my video resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Handbrake encoding is restricted to the *actual* resolution of the video, which can be different from the "*display* resolution" of the video. MediaInfo, for example, only shows the display resolution, which are the same numbers that Handbrake reports.

As a matter of fact, however, Handbrake does not allow to *increase* (upscale) the actual resolution of a video by re-encoding it, but only to *decrease* (downscale) the resolution. So this could be the reason why your encoded video displays a lower resolution without actually being cropped.

Since this is just a guess, you should also try the `Strict` anamorphic mode instead of `Loose` or `None` to keep the maximum source size as the output resolution.